# JOOQ With Oracle: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jooq

I am using JOOQ With Oracle 19. In running a Simple query, it is giving invalid character below. Not sure why its creating quotes ' either.  Java and stack trace SQL below. How can this be fixed for a simple query? It compiles fine however it running produces error.

**Java:**

```
Result<Record1<BigInteger>> test = create.select(PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID)
     .from(PRODUCT)
     .where(PRODUCT.STATUS.eq("submitted")).fetch();
```

**Console Log**

```
 SQL [select `HEALTHCARE`.`PRODUCT`.`PRODUCT_ID` from `HEALTHCARE`.`PRODUCT` where `HEALTHCARE`.`PRODUCT`.`STATUS` = ? 
-- SQL rendered with a free trial version of jOOQ 3.15.2]; ORA-00911: invalid character
```

I copied the SQL query into Oracle SQL Execution Runner, removed the quotes and it works. So not sure what the issue is.

**Update:**

For Oracle 19, should I use Oracle or Oracle 18C?

[image]

Comment: If these strange-looking single quotes were **double quotes**, query would probably have run. Do you have any influence on what kind of quotes will be used? (I don't know, I don't use JOOQ).

Comment: this url explained very well about possible reason behind this error -> https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00911-invalid-character/

Comment: hi @vaibhavsahu I read a lot of resources about ORA-00911, not sure how to fix in relation to JOOQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the `SQLDialect.MYSQL` dialect, instead of the `SQLDialect.ORACLE` one, which explains the backticks in your SQL string.

Comment: posted update about regarding code for Oracle Version, thanks

Comment: It would be 18c, might be worth asking a new question though, because it's not strictly related to this one (the one about the syntax error).